# PyCaret on Google Colab: "Estimator xgboost not available"

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, xgboost, pycaret

I have installed pycaret and xgboost as follows:

```
!pip install pycaret==2.3.10 markupsafe==2.0.1 pyyaml==5.4.1 --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver -qq
!pip install xgboost
```

But when I try to create the following Xgboost model, it throws an error "Estimator xgboost not available."

```
xgboost = create_model('xgboost')
```

Why is this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found the reason. I forgot to add the following lines to my import code:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
import xgboost
```